# Why i have an error when deploy blazor to IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis, blazor-server-side

I have an issue when i deploy blazor to iis:

[image: error]

I searched about this issue and found some ways like: add permission for folder publish,...  but it doesn't work. I saw that 0x8007000d is a error about web.config file

this is my web.config

[image: web.config file]

I try on other devices. It works.

So why my devices doesn't?. I use Visual Studio 2019, .Net 5.0 and deploy blazor to IIS on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you given permission to `IUSR` and it is not working for single device?

Comment: Try using [IIS Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: @शेखर  yes i give it permission but it doesn't work

Comment: Does it work on any other device?

Comment: yes @शेखर it works on other device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this error indicates that the ASP.NET Core module is not installed on the server. Hosting ASP.NET Core applications on IIS requires the Microsoft ASP.NET Core module. You should confirm that the module is installed:

[Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle).